# Java/Jaxb help needed on not overwriting existing file

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm new to JAXB so please be lenient in your comments! Anyway, I have facing problems of my existing xml file to be overwritten each time I run the program which is not what I want. It is suppose to add on to the existing xml. Please help!

CoursesApp.java:

```
package Courses;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class CoursesApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        String courseCode = "", professorName = "", groupIndex = "", classType = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            File file = new File("C:\\Courselist.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Courselist.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Courselist courselist = (Courselist) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(courselist.course.get(0).getclassType());

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        Courselist courselist = new Courselist();
        Course course = new Course();

        do{ 
            System.out.println("(1) Add a student.\n" +
                               "(2) Add a course.\n" +
                               "(3) Exit.\n");
            System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1: 
                    break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Please enter course code:");
                courseCode = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter class type:");
                classType = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter group index:");
                groupIndex = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter professor name:");
                professorName = sc.nextLine();
                course.setcourseCode(courseCode);
                course.setclassType(classType);
                course.setgroupIndex(groupIndex);
                course.setprofessor(professorName);
                courselist.course.add(course);
                try{
                    File file = new File("C:\\Courselist.xml");
                    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Courselist.class);
                    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

                    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

                    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(courselist, file);
                    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(courselist, System.out);

                }catch(JAXBException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    break;
            case 3: //Modify course
                    break;
            default: System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-3.\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while (choice!=3);
    }
}
```

Courselist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<courselist>
    <course>
        <classType>lect</classType>
        <courseCode>2002</courseCode>
        <groupIndex>12</groupIndex>
        <professor>james</professor>
    </course>
</courselist>
```

to the one below if I add another course:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<courselist>
    <course>
        <classType>lect</classType>
        <courseCode>2002</courseCode>
        <groupIndex>12</groupIndex>
        <professor>james</professor>
    </course>
    <course>
        <classType>Lab</classType>
        <courseCode>2001</courseCode>
        <groupIndex>1</groupIndex>
        <professor>john</professor>
    </course>
</courselist>
```

Comment: Just read the file, add objects to the collection you read and save it back.

Answer (score 3):

Thought i already answered this, but answer disappeared...

First of all don't do this:

```
      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

you are catching the exception, dumping text to stdout, then *continuing as if nothing happened*.  this is useless boilerplate added by IDEs, *don't do it*.

since you want to condition your behavior on whether or not the file exists already, i would suggest an `if` block combined with the use of [File.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    public class CoursesApp {

        int choice;
        String courseCode = "", professorName = "", groupIndex = "", classType = "";
        private boolean exists;
        Courselist courselist = new Courselist();
        Course course = new Course();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Courselist courselist = new Courselist();
            Course course = new Course();
            try {

                File file = new File("C:\\Courselist.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Courselist.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                courselist = (Courselist) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(courselist);

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //* OVER HERE *//
            CoursesApp ca = new CoursesApp();
            ca.process(0);
        }

        private void process(int choice) {

            //* PRINT MENU *//
            System.out.println("(1) Add a student.\n"
                    + "(2) Add a course.\n"
                    + "(3) Exit.\n");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    //ADD STUDENTS
                    break;
                case 2:
                    File file = new File("C:\\Course.xml");
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        choice = 4;
                        exists = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("File doesnot exist press 4 to create or 3 to exit: ");
                        choice = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }
                    /*ENTER COURSE DETAILS*/
                    if (choice == 4) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter course code:");
                        courseCode = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Please enter class type:");
                        classType = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Please enter group index:");
                        groupIndex = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Please enter professor name:");
                        professorName = sc.nextLine();
                        course.setcourseCode(courseCode);
                        course.setclassType(classType);
                        course.setgroupIndex(groupIndex);
                        course.setprofessor(professorName);
                        courselist.course.add(course);
                        System.out.println("Are there more records?\n Press 2(yes) or 3(n): ");
                        choice = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();
                        if (choice == 3) {
                            /*END OF RECORDS SO GO AHEAD AND UNMARSHAL*/
                            unmarshal(file, courselist);
                        } else {
                            /*ADD MORE COURSE ITEMS*/
                            process(2);
                        }
                    } else {
                        /*FILE NOT EXIST AND USER SELECTED EXIT*/
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void unmarshal(File file, Courselist courselist) {
            {
                FileWriter fw = null;
                try {
                    JAXBContext jaxbContext =    JAXBContext.newInstance(Courselist.class);
                    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
                    /*EXISTING FILE SO APPEND*/
                    if (exists) {
                        fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(courselist, fw);
                    } 
                    /*CREATE NEW FILE*/
                     else {
                        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(courselist, file);
                    }
                    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(courselist, System.out);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(CoursesApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        fw.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(CoursesApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            process(0);//call and print options
        }
    }
```

This will solve overwriting issue but you need a way to prevent duplication of xml declaration. Hope this helps

I have essentially taken the code posted by the asker and extracted pieces of code to separate methods to understand better. I have also added the checks to see if file exists and append to the file instead of overwriting the contents.

Process() method is for user input and actions need to be performed. In unmarshal(), user input is bound to xml file.

Comment: Suppose this works (I don't know). Is this enlightening in any way as an answer? At the very least, some commentary on what you did that teaches something about the question would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JAXB 2.x **Binder** abstraction for this. [Detailed tutorial](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html).